# How to assign the result from %macro to a macro variable

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have data set with probabilities to purchase a particular product per observation. Here is an example:

```
DATA probabilities; 
INPUT id P_prod1 P_prod2 P_prod3 ; 
DATALINES; 
1 0.02 0.5 0.32
2 0.6 0.08 0.12
3 0.8 0.34 0.001
;
```

I need to calculate the median for each product. Here's how I do that:

```
%macro get_median (product);
proc means data=probabilities median;
var &product ;
output out=median_data (drop=_type _freq_) median=median;
run;
%mend;
```

At this point I can get the median for each product by calling

```
%get_median(P_product1);
```

Now, the last thing that I want to do is to assign the numeric result for the median to a macro variable. My best guess for how to do that would be something like:

```
%let med_P_prod1=%get_median(P_prod1);
```

but unfortunately that does not work.

Can someone help, please?

Cheers!

Comment: Why cannot the median_data dataset serve as your output? You want to store the median values of 3 variables into just one variable ? How will you tell which is which?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to define a `%global` macro variable and set the let statement to the numeric result inside the macro.

```
%macro get_median (product);
proc means data=probabilities median;
var &product ;
output out=median_data (drop=_type _freq_) median=median;
run;
%global macroresult;
proc sql;
select median into :macroresult separated by ' ' from median_data;
quit;
%mend;
```

(That SQL statement is equivalent to LET in that it defines a macro variable, but it is better at getting results from data.)

I'd also recommend just using the dataset in your code rather than putting the value in a macro variable.

Comment: And can I later use this global macro? For example, if I want to divide each observation's probability for product1 by the median of product1...

Comment: Global means the scope of the macro variable is the SAS session, rather than local to the macro it was called from.  So yes, it's available after the macro is called.

Comment: OK, so I did the following: 
 %get_median(P_prod1); 
 %let med_P_prod1=&macroresult; 

 And then repeated that for each of the products that I have. That's not as graceful as I wanted it to be, but it certainly solves the problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's not a very graceful way to solve your problem, because your method for running this isn't very graceful.  If you ask a new question with the overall problem you're trying to solve (I guess, get medians for a bunch of products?) a better solution may be available.